# How to load a yolov7 model in real time detection application?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolov5

I was using yolov5 to do object detection with my customed object and used to load the model like that :

```
model = torch.hub.load("/Users/macbook/Documents/Objection-Detection/yolov5", "custom", source="local",
                       path=os.path.join("/Users/macbook/Documents/Objection-Detection/", model_name),
                       force_reload=True)
```

I trained my custom object in yolov7 google colab and after downloading the model I want to load it in my application in PyCharm to make detection. So can someone tell me how can I did it like yolov5 ?

Ps: don't mention my english mistakes I'm a french guy whom is still learning english

What I'm asking for is if there is a way to load yolov7 model like that :

```
model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "yolov5s", pretrained=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no Yolov7 models in `torch.hub`. Check out:

https://pytorch.org/hub/

and search for Yolo. The only model you will find are Yolov5 and YoloP